# How to use script in MATLAB allowing functions to be declared?

Tags: matlab, function

While making GUI I've came into this problem:
Using script (S) in function (A) makes other functions (B,C,D..., which are declared in function (A)) as undeclared while executing script (S), it happens on MATLAB version R2016b, however everything works fine in MATLAB R2015b.

Basically I have a bunch of axes, and axesPushScript.m script, which executes on click.
Inside script i got this line:

```
autorange_Callback(handles.autorange, eventdata, handles);
```

Inside my main function I've got this:

```
function autorange_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (hObject.Value==1)
   axis(handles.axesSpectra, 'tight');
   axesSpectra_ButtonDownFcn(handles.axesSpectra,eventdata,handles);
else axis(handles.axesSpectra, 'manual');
end
```

get this error message on MATLAB R2016b:

```
 Undefined function or variable 'autorange_Callback'.

Error in axesPushScript (line 44)
autorange_Callback(handles.autorange, eventdata, handles);

Error in SNOM_alpha_4>axesTrace_ButtonDownFcn (line 463)
axesPushScript;

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in SNOM_alpha_4 (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)SNOM_alpha_4('axesTrace_ButtonDownFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating Axes ButtonDownFcn
```

Any ideas of how I could fix it?

%---------------------------------------------------------------
EDIT:
adding .rar file with a simple one button example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsgxb9xt1s6hbvp/junk.rar?dl=0

Comment: Are the files in the same directory or in MATLAB's path? This question doesn't really make any sense as currently written. Please see [mcve].

Comment: All the functions and scripts are in one folder (except MATLAB internal functions, which have default path), running different versions of MATLAB on two separate computers.

Comment: So you have a [**local function**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) (a function, in a file, which isn't the main function of that file) which you can't access from another script? That would be because it's a **local function**. Put it in its own script, named `autorange_Callback.m`

Comment: Wolfie, thanks, that might fix the problem, however I'm still confused of why it works on one computer. I'm now trying to replicate the problem by doing simple one button GUI as excaza suggested.

Comment: The visibility of local functions called by scripts changed in R2016b. Check the MATLAB release notes - this is marked as incompatibility.